# Trying to build PHP and GD with PNG and JPEG support

Tags: php, gd

The browser displays the error message

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function imagecreatefrompng() in...

Here is the source code that fails:

```
$img = imagecreatefrompng($file);
```

It's a native PHP function.

I am intent on building both GD and PHP.

The GD `libgd-2.2.4` library was built just fine:

```
Support for Zlib:                 yes
Support for PNG library:          yes
Support for JPEG library:         yes
Support for WebP library:         no
Support for TIFF library:         no
Support for Freetype 2.x library: yes
Support for Fontconfig library:   no
Support for Xpm library:          yes
Support for liq library:          no
Support for pthreads:             yes
```

I used the commands:

```
./configure \
  --prefix=/home/stephane/programs/install \
  --with-jpeg=/home/stephane/programs/install \
  --with-png=/home/stephane/programs/install \
  --with-freetype=/home/stephane/programs/install \
  --with-zlib=/home/stephane/programs/install \
  --with-xpm

make
make install
```

The `make` and `make install` commands were successful.

The PHP `php-5.6.30` engine was also built fine:

```
checking for GD support... yes
checking for the location of libvpx... no
checking for the location of libjpeg... /home/stephane/programs/install
checking for the location of libpng... /home/stephane/programs/install
checking for the location of libXpm... no
checking for FreeType 2... /home/stephane/programs/install
checking for T1lib support... no
checking whether to enable truetype string function in GD... yes

checking for gdSetErrorMethod in -lgd... yes
checking for gdImageCreateFromPng in -lgd... yes
checking for gdImageCreateFromWebp in -lgd... no
checking for gdImageCreateFromJpeg in -lgd... yes
checking for gdImageCreateFromXpm in -lgd... yes
checking for gdImageStringFT in -lgd... yes
checking for gdVersionString in -lgd... yes
checking for gdImageCreate in -lgd... yes
```

I used the commands:

```
./configure \
  --prefix=/home/stephane/programs/install \
  --with-apxs2=/home/stephane/programs/install/apache/bin/apxs \
  --with-config-file-path=/home/stephane/programs/php-5.6.30/ \
  --with-mysql=/home/stephane/programs/install/mariadb \
  --with-mysqli=/home/stephane/programs/install/mariadb/bin/mysql_config \
  --with-pdo-mysql=/home/stephane/programs/install/mariadb \
  --with-zlib-dir=/home/stephane/programs/install \
  --with-jpeg-dir=/home/stephane/programs/install \
  --with-png-dir=/home/stephane/programs/install \
  --with-gd=/home/stephane/programs/install \
  --enable-gd-native-ttf \
  --with-freetype-dir=/home/stephane/programs/install \
  --enable-ftp \
  --enable-xml \
  --enable-zip \
  --with-bz2 \
  --enable-wddx \
  --enable-libgcc \
  --without-pear \
  --enable-mbstring \
  --enable-intl \
  --enable-calendar \
  --with-openssl \
  --with-curl \
  --enable-debug \
  --disable-phar \
  --enable-fpm \
  --with-oci8=instantclient,/home/stephane/programs/oracle/instantclient_11_2

make
make install
```

The `make` and `make install` commands were also successful.

Here are the library files that were created:

```
$ ll /home/stephane/programs/install/lib/
total 22M
-rw-r--r-- 1 stephane 6,3M juin  12 14:30 libfreetype.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 stephane 1,1K juin  12 14:30 libfreetype.la*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 stephane   21 juin  12 14:30 libfreetype.so -> libfreetype.so.6.13.0*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 stephane   21 juin  12 14:30 libfreetype.so.6 -> libfreetype.so.6.14.0*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 stephane 3,0M juin  12 14:30 libfreetype.so.6.13.0*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 stephane 3,1M juin  10 13:11 libfreetype.so.6.14.0*
-rw-r--r-- 1 stephane 1,7M juin  12 15:08 libgd.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 stephane 1,2K juin  12 15:08 libgd.la*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 stephane   14 juin  12 15:08 libgd.so -> libgd.so.3.0.4*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 stephane   14 juin  12 15:08 libgd.so.3 -> libgd.so.3.0.4*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 stephane 1,1M juin  12 15:08 libgd.so.3.0.4*
-rw-r--r-- 1 stephane 2,2M juin   7 12:36 libjpeg.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 stephane  938 juin   7 12:36 libjpeg.la*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 stephane   16 juin   7 12:36 libjpeg.so -> libjpeg.so.9.2.0*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 stephane   16 juin   7 12:36 libjpeg.so.9 -> libjpeg.so.9.2.0*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 stephane 1,2M juin   7 12:36 libjpeg.so.9.2.0*
-rw-r--r-- 1 stephane 1,7M juin  10 12:43 libpng16.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 stephane  958 juin  10 12:43 libpng16.la*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 stephane   19 juin  10 12:43 libpng16.so -> libpng16.so.16.29.0*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 stephane   19 juin  10 12:43 libpng16.so.16 -> libpng16.so.16.29.0*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 stephane 905K juin  10 12:43 libpng16.so.16.29.0*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 stephane   10 juin  10 12:43 libpng.a -> libpng16.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 stephane   11 juin  10 12:43 libpng.la -> libpng16.la*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 stephane   11 juin  10 12:43 libpng.so -> libpng16.so*
-rw-r--r-- 1 stephane 151K juin   5 22:46 libz.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 stephane   14 juin   5 22:46 libz.so -> libz.so.1.2.11*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 stephane   14 juin   5 22:46 libz.so.1 -> libz.so.1.2.11*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 stephane 120K juin   5 22:46 libz.so.1.2.11*
drwxrwxr-x 4 stephane 4,0K juin   8 17:08 php/
drwxrwxr-x 2 stephane 4,0K juin  12 15:08 pkgconfig/
```

But a look at the `phpinfo` shows an incomplete GD section:

```
GD Support  enabled
GD headers Version  2.2.4
GD library Version  2.2.4
GIF Read Support    enabled
GIF Create Support  enabled
WBMP Support    enabled
XPM Support enabled
libXpm Version  30411
XBM Support enabled
```

There are no default packages installed:

```
$ sudo apt-cache show libpng
N: Impossible de trouver le paquet libpng
E: Aucun paquet n'a été trouvé
[stephane@stephane-ThinkPad-X201 fatec]
$ sudo apt-cache show libjpeg
N: Impossible de trouver le paquet libjpeg
E: Aucun paquet n'a été trouvé
```

Here is a bit about my OS and machine:

```
$ uname -a
Linux stephane-ThinkPad-X201 4.4.0-79-generic #100-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 17 19:58:14 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

My Apache configuration does point to the right PHP directory:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    PHPIniDir "/home/stephane/programs/php-5.6.30"
</IfModule>

$ ll /home/stephane/programs/php-5.6.30/php.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 stephane 73K juin  12 14:05 /home/stephane/programs/php-5.6.30/php.ini
```

Comment: consider sharing some of your code, that contains error, or not working.

Comment: It's a native PHP function call. There is no more code needed.

Comment: Again, the error says that the function is undefined.

Comment: This is gonna be one of those very tricky problems. Might be relevant to share your OS and more specifics of how you built PHP and GD.

Comment: Did you restart the web server after making all your config changes?

Comment: @j08691 Yes I did, a stop followed by a start, with a non responding request in between.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the issue.

I just had to do a `make clean` command before doing the `make` command.

Now I have the GD enabled as I needed:

```
GD Support  enabled
GD headers Version  2.2.4
GD library Version  2.2.4
FreeType Support    enabled
FreeType Linkage    with freetype
FreeType Version    2.8.0
GIF Read Support    enabled
GIF Create Support  enabled
JPEG Support    enabled
libJPEG Version unknown
PNG Support enabled
libPNG Version  1.6.29
WBMP Support    enabled
XPM Support enabled
libXpm Version  30411
XBM Support enabled
```

I always and wrongly assumed the `./configure` command would void the compiled objects. Not so.